# Network Bridge Over a Subnet

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I am trying to figure out how to make a flat network by bridging over a subnet using 2 Ubuntu guests so that everything in the other subnets can talk to each other without restriction.

Configuration is as follows,

```
192.168.0.0 <[eth0--Guest1--eth1]> 172.16.0.0 <[eth1--Guest2--eth0]> 192.168.0.0
```

1. The 172.16.0.0 is essentially a cable between 2 hosts
2. I can't use the eth0 interfaces as gateway's, because I have different gateway's on each 192.168.0.0 subnet that my guests have to use
3. I would rather not set a wack-load of static routes on all my guests in the 192.168.0.0 subnets

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

*EDIT*

I have 2 VMHosts in my home lab. I am trying to simulate segregated network traffic. I don't have money to buy the proper network gear to setup VMware as it was intended, with VLANs, etc. So I am trying to hack a solution together.

NIC0 from each host is connected to an external switch. On the VMware side NIC0 mapps to the external interface of a high availability pfSense cluster, which is my firewall / router solution. The internal interface of the pfSense cluster is connected to the 192.168.0.0 subnet. The 192.168.0.0 subnet also maps to NIC2. NIC2 on Host A has a direct connection to NIC2 on Host B. I can set NIC2 as on either the 192.168.0.0 or the 172.16.0.0 subnet.

The issue is that traffic will not traverse the link that is connected to NIC2 unless you point directly at it.

Is there a way to bridge that gap?

4 more reputation points and I can add a better diagram :)

```
                  Internet
                     |
                     |
                   modem
                     |
                     |
                   Switch
                     |
                     |
    --------------------------------------
    |                                    |
  HostA                                HostB
   NIC0                                 NIC0
    |                                    |
    |                                    |
pfSense--NIC1  <--Heartbeat-->  NIC1--pfSense
    |                                    |
    |                                    |
----------------                  ----------------
|  192.168.0.0 |                  |  192.168.0.0 |
|     Subnet   |                  |     Subnet   |
|              |                  |              |
|              |                  |              | 
|              |                  |              | 
|              |                  |              | 
|              |                  |              | 
|      RouterA |-NIC2 <----> NIC2-| RouterB      | 
|              |    172.16.0.0    |              | 
|              |        or        |              |
|              |    192.168.0.0   |              | 
|              |                  |              | 
----------------                  ----------------
```

Comment: your guest2 has to operate on a different subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24)

Comment: If I move a guest from Host A to Host B then I would have to re-IP it. I am trying to shy away from that. I would like to be able to move any guest from Host A to Host B and vise versa, and still have that guest talk to any other guest on either host. Thanks,

Comment: Then you have a problem...

Comment: Maybe it's me but i'm not following your question at all. Are [] hosts? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Bridging over a subnet confuses me. Can you rephrase, and do a better diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue from the VMware side without the use of routers/bridges. I basically had to attach the internal NIC of each pfSense, to NIC2 from each host, to create one joined broadcast domain that spanned the 2 hosts.